# I want to convert my raw query to query builder

Tags: laravel, postgresql, query-builder

I m new in laravel
Actually I have a auth table which is link to the other table based on the user type. I want user info from corresponding tables so i use raw query now i want to convert it into query builder, Please help

```
$data = DB::select("SELECT srr.id,srr.created_at,srr.fromid,srr.toid,srr.from_usertype,au.firstname_admin,au.lastname_admin,cd.name as to_compayname,COALESCE(unionSub1.firstname,NULL) as from_firstname, unionSub1.lastname as from_lastname
                 from service_request_reviews as srr
                 left join (
                     (select authid, firstname, lastname from userdetails)
                     union (select authid, firstname, lastname from yachtdetail)
                     union (select authid, firstname, lastname from talentdetails)
                     union (select authid, name as firstname, COALESCE(NULL,NULL) as lastname from companydetails)
                 ) unionSub1 on unionSub1.authid = srr.fromid
                 left join auths as au on au.id = srr.fromid
                 LEFT JOIN companydetails as cd ON cd.authid = srr.toid WHERE srr.isdeleted = '0' AND srr.parent_id1 = '0' " );
```

I have tried this and its working fine without union. I don't know how to use multiple unions inside left join.

```
$data = DB::table('service_request_reviews as srr')
       ->select('srr.id','srr.created_at','srr.fromid','srr.toid','srr.from_usertype','au.firstname_admin','au.lastname_admin','cd.name as to_compayname')
->leftjoin('auths as au', 'au.id', '=' ,'srr.fromid')
                ->leftjoin('companydetails as cd', 'cd.authid', '=', 'srr.toid')
 ->where('srr.isdeleted', '0')
 ->where('srr.parent_id', '0');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define union as query builder for that table Like:

```
$yachtdetail = DB::table("yachtdetail")
                    ->select('authid', 'firstname', 'lastname');

$talentdetails = DB::table('talentdetails')
                    ->select('authid', 'firstname', 'lastname');
```

Now you can use like:

```
$data = DB::table('service_request_reviews as srr')
       ->select('srr.id','srr.created_at','srr.fromid','srr.toid','srr.from_usertype','au.firstname_admin','au.lastname_admin','cd.name as to_compayname')
       ->leftjoin('auths as au', 'au.id', '=' ,'srr.fromid')
       ->leftjoin('companydetails as cd', 'cd.authid', '=', 'srr.toid')
       ->where('srr.isdeleted', '0')
       ->where('srr.parent_id', '0')
       ->union($yachtdetail)
       ->union($talentdetails)
       ->get();
```

Here is the link for the documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#unions

**Edited:**

In your case you can try something like this:

```
$queryBuilder = DB::table('service_request_reviews as srr')
       ->select('srr.id','srr.created_at','srr.fromid','srr.toid','srr.from_usertype','au.firstname_admin','au.lastname_admin','cd.name as to_compayname')
       ->leftjoin('auths as au', 'au.id', '=' ,'srr.fromid')
       ->leftjoin('companydetails as cd', 'cd.authid', '=', 'srr.toid')
       ->leftjoin(DB::raw("((select authid, firstname, lastname from userdetails)
                     union (select authid, firstname, lastname from yachtdetail)
                     union (select authid, firstname, lastname from talentdetails)
                     union (select authid, name as firstname, null as lastname from companydetails)) as unionSub1"), function($join){

                        $join->on(DB::raw('unionSub1.authid'), '=', DB::raw('srr.fromid'));
       })
       ->where('srr.isdeleted', '0')
       ->where('srr.parent_id', '0');

$data = $queryBuilder->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i want to convert this ```
left join (
                     (select authid, firstname, lastname from userdetails)
                     union (select authid, firstname, lastname from yachtdetail)
                     union (select authid, firstname, lastname from talentdetails)
                     union (select authid, name as firstname, COALESCE(NULL,NULL) as lastname from companydetails)
                 ) unionSub1 on unionSub1.authid = srr.fromid
``` raw query to query builder

Comment: @DeekshaRana please check the `Edited` section

Comment: Thanks for the reply again, I m getting this error with edited query ```
message: "SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias```

Comment: From updated solution above^^^, Just run the `dd($queryBuilder->toSql());` before getting the data and share the query.

Comment: Updated solution @DeekshaRana try now. `Edited` section.

Comment: I am getting this error ```syntax error at or near "as" COALESCE(NULL,NULL) as lastname from companydetails) as unionSub1"```

Comment: replace `COALESCE(NULL,NULL) as last_name`  with `null as last_name`

Comment: I have tried getting same issue ```syntax error at or near "as" (select authid, name as firstname, null as lastname from companydetails) as unionSub1```

Comment: @DeekshaRana updated solution once again added missing closing `)` brackets. Try now.

Comment: Now getting this error ```ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "unionSub1"```

Comment: Now do print `dd($queryBuilder->toSql());`  once agian and see the difference b/w your actual query and this.. could identify the issue.

Comment: My problem is solved with this line ```$join->on(DB::raw('unionSub1.authid'), DB::raw('='),DB::raw('srr.fromid'));```. thanks for you help

Comment: Here is how you can..http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work if you are not aware.